# springboot start failed with linux server installed dynatrace agent(APM)

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a problem to start springboot API app. (2.1.5 ver)
It works well with every server except server that installed dynatrace (APM).
I tried to start app that simple type with minimum springboot library, but it failed too.
I want to start application this server. Please help.

**Error Log**

```
2021-01-12 06:27:09.742|main                     |INFO |WorkerApplication:50|Starting WorkerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ip-10-5-253-160 with PID 24961 (/opt/apiservice_v2/apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /opt/apiservice_v2)
2021-01-12 06:27:09.751|main                     |INFO |WorkerApplication:679|The following profiles are active: live
2021-01-12 06:27:11.825|main                     |ERROR|SpringApplication:858|Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.beanNameViewResolver
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.test.ee.servicenew.apiservice.WorkerApplication.main(WorkerApplication.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@442d9b6e]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$$Lambda$188/296347592.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$$Lambda$186/247944893.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:125)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method init in class javax/servlet/Filter has illegal modifiers: 0x1
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
2021-01-12 06:27:11.834|main                     |WARN |SpringApplication:839|Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@442d9b6e]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$$Lambda$188/296347592.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:600)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:905)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:877)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:826)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.test.ee.servicenew.apiserviceft.WorkerApplication.main(WorkerApplication.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method init in class javax/servlet/Filter has illegal modifiers: 0x1
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml** (simple libriry version)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- springboot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**WorkerApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorkerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe what it means "that simple type with minimum springboot library". Not understood

Comment: @HoRn necessary library except additional libriries in the pom.xml. ex) mybatis , db connect, ...